# Retrieve table name from collection

Tags: product-collection, flat, ee-1.13.1.0

How can I retrieve table name from Magento collection. My case: observer listens `catalog_product_collection_load_before` event. Here we can get product collection. But I need exactly which table is used for this collection. Magento uses flat tables if it is enabled, otherwise `catalog_product_entity` table. I have enabled flat tables but sometimes Magento uses eav table for product collection (on catalog/category/view request). Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way to do it.
Let's say `$collection` is your product collection.

```
$from = $collection->getSelect()->getPart('from');
$table = $from['e']['tableName'];
```

`$table` is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 6):

A collection can have multiple tables associated to it depending on whether joins are used or not, but if you want to pull the main table (the one used when calling `from()` on the select object) then you can call:

```
$table = $collection->getMainTable();
```

Outside of this if you want to find the any other tables involved you will need to pull `from` from the select object and inspect the results:

```
$from = $collection->getSelect()->getPart(Zend_Db_Select::FROM);
```